# Exclude a specific method call (inside another method) from aspectj

Tags: spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I'm trying to exclude a specific method call inside another method from being intercepted:

```
public Class A {
   public void foo1() {...}

   public void foo2() {
     foo1();
   }

}
```

I only want to exclude the foo1 calls made from foo2, and not the other calls: someAObject.foo1() & someAobject.foo2() should be included.

Does anyone know how to do this using spring aop?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you stop using spring, barring that, if you can write two pieces of around advice for each call, you can set a `ThreadLocal<Boolean>` in the first and `proceed`, and check it in the second, not `proceed`ing if its set. pretty ugly hack.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
execution(* A.*(..)) && !execution(* A.foo2(..))
```

Comment: But then wouldn't foo2 be excluded? (I don't want to do that).

Comment: around: call(* A.foo1()) && execution(* A.foo2())

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand the question. You can't do it with Spring AOP (without the ThreadLocal trick suggested in the other answer).